# how can I locate this my ms access file easier?

Tags: database, vb.net

here's my current code from the [**internet**](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p4.html)

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\CSI_FOREX\Dropbox\CSI Files\Euel CSI\cctvGmapVBnew\cctvGmapVBnew\database\sample\cctvGmapVbDatabase.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()

    MsgBox("Database is now open")

    con.Close()

    MsgBox("Database is now Closed")
```

now, this code works. is there any way that I can shorten it? its on the same folder as my project.. `\database\sample\myFile`

I will have problems if I am going to deploy this as it is. thanks.

Comment: create new directory for data it is safe

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you said.. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.IO


dbSource = "Data Source = " & Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "database\sample\cctvGmapVbDatabase.mdb")
```

Comment: thanks, worked. another thing, I have added the database to my Resources.. will this work, or something like it : `dbSource = "Data Source = " & My.Resources.myFile`

Comment: That is a different question and you need to post a new question on the site for it.